# Terminal window inside Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Does `Xcode` have an area I can open up a terminal shell session *inside* `Xcode`? `Android Studio` has a window you can open up at the bottom by the console `logcat` window that will start a terminal session. Does `Xcode` have anything like this?

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I just like to keep it in the IDE if I can, so I don't have 2 separate windows. Really more of a preference than wanting it from a practical standpoint.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such a thing in `Xcode`. We have to fall back to external `Terminal` window.

If you really want to do it, you can add a build phase and run script that opens the `Terminal` - but that might not be what you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: use Spotlight on macOS

Comment: Useful for me: to make it open in a new tab if already have a terminal instance running you can go to Dock preferences and set `Prefer tabs when opening documents` to `Always`.

Answer (score 85):

1. Create executable shell script with the following contents and save it anywhere

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   open -a Terminal "`pwd`"
   ```

   - Add execute permissions to your script: `$ chmod +x <YourShellScript>`
2. In the Xcode menu bar, Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Behaviors.
3. Add a Custom behavior
4. Name it "Open Terminal", or whatever.
5. (Optional) Configure a hotkey for the behavior by tapping on the <kbd>⌘</kbd>
6. (Optional) Input hotkey combination
7. Checkmark Run, select you script from step 1.
8. Use it within Xcode.

#### Image with numbers corresponding to steps

[image]

Comment: You missed a step - the script created in step one must have executable permission for it to be selectable in Step 7.

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Comment: For those who have not written much shell script before (like me).
You will need to add `#!/bin/bash` at top of your shell file

Comment: 1. quickly create open terminal script: $ `echo '#!/bin/bash\nopen -a Terminal "\`pwd\`"' > ~/terminal.sh && chmod +x ~/terminal.sh`
2. Add Behaviour in Xcode, add shortcut ctrl+cmd+T
3. Select Run > choose terminal.sh from home directory

Comment: Thanks for your solution, i changed Terminal to iTerm, and it works also very well.

Comment: Im not mac user so I just copy pasted with `$` and wonder why it is not working :D. Thanks dear!

Comment: If you wonder how to **use** the new behavior: `Xcode -> Behaviors -> Open Terminal`

Comment: you may have to scroll to find the `Run` checkbox

Answer (score 5):

Relatedly, now in Xcode 8, you can have your program run automatically in Terminal rather than using the Xcode Console. Just go to Edit Scheme > Run > Options and set Console at the bottom to Terminal.

[image]

And here's the Xcode 15.0 pulldown version:
[image: Xcode 15 pulldown:]

Comment: No options like this for me, maybe it is platform specific/other dependencies?

Comment: That's strange. I added a picture above to show where it is.  Obviously it's for OSX apps only

Comment: Wherever it's been moved in 2022, I can't find it. And I think it's only there for some schemes, not others.

Comment: So, looks exactly the same to me in Xcode 15. If I create a new empty MacOS project, the option is exactly the same, except that it's a pulldown (added above).